# How to set ItemsSource of a ComboBox, if it was present in an ItemsCotrol

Tags: wpf, data-binding

ComboBox items were not displaying, if we try to keep that combobox in an ItemsCotrol. [Please click here for understanding my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0If51.png)

My requirement is to keep a combobox in an ItemsControl, so that the ItemsControl qill be having 5 Comboboxes in it and each combox will be having a collection of items which we can select. So for that i tried with the below code and able to get the comboboxes in the ItemsControl, but the comboboxes collection is getting filled, any suggestions or workaround please..

```
<xamDataPresenter:Field Label="Reqs" BindingType="Unbound" Row="0" Column="4">
                        <xamDataPresenter:Field.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type xamDataPresenter:CellValuePresenter}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xamDataPresenter:CellValuePresenter}">
                                            <ItemsControl Name="I" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataItem.CollectionCount}">
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataItem.Collection}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </xamDataPresenter:Field.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                    </xamDataPresenter:Field>
```

Comment: You're missing an ItemsSource on the combobox?

Comment: Your combobox code doesn't make much sense. Why do you create one TextBlock as ComboBoxItem, instead of providing an collection of items to the Combobox (similarly to what you did with the ItemsControl). Since currently, your only item is actually a TextBlock element itself (the item is is not the object provided by the Polarity property!), you would need to provide that TextBlock element for ComboBox.SelectedItem to select it; which of course also is rather unpractical, if you think about it..

Comment: Er.... what is this supposed to do: `<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`? This edit of your code doesn't make even less sense...

Comment: You are saying "_each combox will be having a collection of items which we can select_". So, start asking yourself: Where are those collections of items for each ComboBox, and thus, how would a binding to reach those collections look like?

Comment: I suspect he's trying to do something like:
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

where he can pick which properties to display in each of the items in the dropdown.
But even with those edit changes, he still needs an itemsSource so the combobox knows what items should be in it.

Comment: @emybob, to me it is entirely unclear what the purpose and content of those comboboxes should be.

Comment: Thanks emybob and elgonzo for your quick reply, could you please check once the requirement hyperlink that i kept, so that you can understand my requirement, thanks..

Comment: I don't know what the purpose of the edits of your code in the question is. It doesn't really help clarifying what you are trying to do...

Comment: The screenshot you linked shows just some empty comboboxes. How should i know what the content and purpose of the comboboxes should be, if all i am seeing is a picture of empty comboboxes without so much as a sliver of an explanation about their intended content and purpose. See my second comment where i responded to you saying "_each combox will be having a collection of items which we can select_".

Comment: HI emybob and elgonzo, i tried by giving itemssource to combobox with a collection, but still the combobox is not displaying the collection that i have provided, could you please tell me whether my requirement is clear, or do i need to provide more information emybob and elgonzo, thanks.

Comment: "_please tell me whether my requirement is clear, or do i need to provide more information_" Didn't i just do exactly that in my last comment? o_O???

Comment: Could you update your code with what you've put to bind it?

Comment: Hi emybob, i just updated the code with which i was trying, can i do like that? could you please suggest me the way to achieve my requirement, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I've written up the most basic of ItemsControl to try and explain how these things work, which you can hopefully adapt for whatever your using for your dataitems.

So in your window's resources i've created a datatemplate. This respresents a repeating step and will be based on a DataItem. In this case my DataItem has 2 properties: DataItemProperty(string) and SelectedItem. The SelectedItem will have the same DataType of whatever it is your planning on showing in the combobox.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="StepTemplate">
    <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataItemProperty}" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemsToSelectFrom, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The combobox in this example will be getting a list of available options from the code behind/viewmodel and not the DataItem, but when you select something it updates the SelectedItem property on the DataItem.
Then to show your items:

```
  <ItemsControl 
        Focusable="False"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StepTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Steps, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

So Steps is a property in my codebehind/viewmodel that will determine how many 'rows' get displayed.
The itemsControl allows you to add repeating sets of data easily, without having to write the same xaml multiple times. 
Hope that helps?

Comment: Two points: 1. "a property in my codebehind/viewmodel" -- your XAML is not binding to a codebehind property, and the two differ. 2. You don't need to put `Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a binding to a property that cannot update the source.

Comment: it is binding to code behind. i just havent written it all out, because i'm not doing everything for you. You need to think for yourself as well, or you  won't learn.

Comment: I’m not OP. I’m an expert trying to help you improve an answer that demonstrates a poor understanding of the material. Are you assuming the code will set DataContext = this? That is very poor practice.